# Apply the same chain of arel clauses to different relations

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

I have two ActiveRecord relations, call them `rel1` and `rel2`. They each get various different `joins` and `where` clauses added to them.

I want to apply a certain identical sequence of clauses to each of them, and I don't want to repeat myself.

One way to do this would be to make a function:

```
def without_orders rel
   rel.joins("LEFT JOIN orders ON customers.id = orders.customer_id").where("customers.id IS NULL")
end

rel1 = Customer
rel2 = Customer

# add a bunch of clauses to rel1
# add some other clauses to rel2

rel1 = without_orders(rel1)
rel2 = without_orders(rel2)
```

Ideally, I wouldn't have `without_orders` as a separate function. I would somehow put the `joins` and `where` in something local to `func`, and apply that thing to `rel1` and `rel2`.

Is that possible? If not, what is the right approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make them all into inidivual scopes:

```
scope :without_orders, -> { joins("LEFT JOIN orders ON customers.id = orders.customer_id").where(customers: { id: nil }) }
```

And then you can chain it with other scopes.

```
Customer.without_orders.where(foo: bar)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a good candidate for an activesupport concern

```
# app/models/concerns/customer_related.rb

module CustomerRelated

  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods

    def whithout_orders
      joins("LEFT JOIN orders ON customers.id = orders.customer_id").where("customers.id IS NULL")
    end

  end

end
```

And then in your models you include it:

```
include CustomerRelated
```

And then you can use it like a scope on any model that includes the concern

```
Rel1.without_orders
```

or

```
Rel2.without_orders
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there an advantage to this approach over the one evanbikes suggests?

Comment: This is the standard way to add similar functionality across models.

Comment: I've upvoted your answer because of that advantage, but marked the other as accepted, because it requires less code and keeps the logic local to the model, which seems more natural. Scopes may sometimes need to be shared across models, but it is likely more common they do not.

Comment: Yeah - I think I misread your question.  I assumed rel1 and rel2 were instances of two different classes.  Scope is the way to go and evanbikes answer is right on.